# Set and get cursor position? JAVA w/ OpenGL

Tags: java, mouse

In `Java /w OpenGL`, how do I get and set the cursor position?
A lot of people say to use `GLUTWarpPointer` for setting the position, but which Class is that?

Comment: There is not OpenGL + Java. You can use some bind library like JOGL and JOGL does not have GLUTWarpPointer class.

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with OpenGL. It's about how to move the mouse pointer with Java; OpenGL doesn't change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use OpenGL specific libraries to do this, it can easily be accomplished with the Robot class, which contains a [`mouseMove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseMove%28int,%20int%29) method - it does what it says on the tin.

As far as I'm aware both Robot and GLUTWarpPointer generate low level system events to move the mouse, thus achieving the same thing. I assume you're using JOGL which as far as I know doesn't expose the mouse moving functionality of GLUTWarpPointer, so if that's correct `Robot` is probably the only sensible option.

Comment: But that doesn't move it relative to the window, also, I need to know how to get the relative position of the mouse, btw, Component.getLocationOnScreen().x -How do I get the component if it's a window made in OpenGL